# Why this C++ lambda funtion returns 1?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a lambda function as below, it explicitly declares `int` as its return type, but in its realization, it does nothing. Besides, it prints out its return value. To my surprise, it compiles without error and returns 1. Who knows the reason?

```
auto lambda = [](int a) -> int{};
cout << lambda << endl;
```

Comment: Try adding the _return_ statement to your lambda function like `return a;` and then printing the `std::cout << lambda(123)` to observe different results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I print out its return value

No. You're printing out the lambda itself. For this case it converts to function pointer, then converts to `bool` implicitly. For non-null pointer the converted result is `true` (i.e. `1` in this case. You can use `std::boolalpha` to get the print result as `true` or `false` like `cout << boolalpha<< lambda << endl;`).

If you want to print out the return value of the lambda, it should be

```
cout << lambda(42) << endl;
```

but note that flowing off the end of a value-returning function (except `main`) without a [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes) is undefined behavior, this is true for lambdas too.

---

BTW: Only lambdas without captures can convert to function pointer implicitly, while lambdas with captures can't.

Comment: Isn't UB that the lambda does not have a ```return```statement?

Comment: @francesco Yes it is. Added to the answer.

Comment: I though it should be ill-formed, that's kinda strange that it ever  is allowed to compile.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You mean *no return statement* or *print out the lambda directly*?

Comment: @songyuanyao no return statement in lambda at all.. which might be different from having a return value in a function but flow-control around it (e.g. by `goto`). Direct printing also odd, unless there was some overload for << that took an aggregate (and old gcc considers lambda to be one, which is implementation oddity..you even could reach the captured values)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Well, yes. I think it's just not easy to analyze all the branches in a function. While direct printing is valid; even it doesn't make sense mostly.

Comment: @songyuanyao yep. Though all three "big players" on scene do that and complain. EIther that was some permissive mode , or not ms\gcc\clang.